# SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle

I have enclosed the table and the insert statement I am working on.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (
        DRIVER_ID       INTEGER     NOT NULL
    , FNAME     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    , LNAME     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    , ADDRESS   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , SALARY    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , DOB       DATE            NOT NULL
    , SHIFTS    VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL
    , SSN       CHAR(11)    NOT NULL
    , PHONE         INTEGER         NOT NULL
    , HIRING_DATE   DATE            NOT NULL
    , EMAIL     VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
);
```

When I run this insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO EMP (DRIVER_ID, FNAME, LNAME, ADDRESS, SALARY, DOB, SHIFTS, SSN, PHONE, HIRING_DATE, EMAIL) 
VALUES (SEQ_EMP.NEXTVAL,'Emma', 'Johnson', '123 Main Street', 'DIRECT DEPOSIT', '31 JANUARY,1988', 'MORNING', '579-45-6666', '410-555-1112', '16 DECEMBER,2013', 'ejohnson@fakemail.com');
```

I get this error message

```
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Answer (score 5):

Lets look at this logically.  The error message is saying "invalid number".  Oracle is saying to you "I am expecting a number, but you gave me something that isn't a number".

Looking at the table SQL, you can see that the table has two columns whose type is a number type (actually `INTEGER`).  These are `DRIVER_ID` and `PHONE`.  (The other columns don't matter now ... because they won't expect a number as the value.)

Now look at the insert SQL, and the values corresponding to those columns.

- The value inserted into the `DRIVER_ID` column comes from `SEQ_EMP.NEXTVAL` ... which I would assume has type `INTEGER`.  That means, you won't get an error from there.
- The value inserted into the `PHONE` column is `'410-555-1112'`.  But, hey, that isn't a number.  Its a string!  And besides a (mathematical) number doesn't have hyphen characters embedded in it!

In short, if you are going to store phone numbers with `-` (or `+` or space) characters embedded in them, you can't use `INTEGER` as the column type.

Answer (score 0):

In your table DDL change

```
PHONE         INTEGER         NOT NULL
```

to

```
PHONE         CHAR(12)         NOT NULL
```

as previously mentioned by user Stephen C using CHAR instead of INTEGER.

Also, those DATE fields will have to be converted to CHAR datatypes as well or you'll have to format your INSERT to handle the date format properly.  Those fields are:

```
, DOB       DATE            NOT NULL
, HIRING_DATE   DATE            NOT NULL
```

If you chose to keep the columns as DATEs, then in your insert use (for the above-mentioned columns) the following...

```
,to_date('31-JANUARY-1988','DD-MONTH-YYYY')
,to_date('16-DECEMBER-2013','DD-MONTH-YYYY')
```

The above won't give you *exactly* what you are looking for -- e.g. `16 DECEMBER,2013` -- but it will work and format the date with hyphens -- e.g. `16-DECEMBER-2013`.  If you need further information on the to_date() function for Oracle for formatting and for other sundry information, please refer to the Oracle docs or search on "Oracle TO_DATE" via your favorite browser.

HTH

Comment: You should rather use `varchar` instead of `char`.